# wurf introduction

Tags: java-me, midlet, wurfl

How do I setup wrufl so that I can begin querying for information regarding phone models ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download wurfl from http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/java/installation.php and deploy onto tomcat

Comment: That page is very obsolete. The 1.0.x java API is available here: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/njava/